# Pattern for a vector space basis expansion

Tags: pattern-matching, vector

I'd like a pattern which matches an expansion of a vector in a given basis, so mathematically any expression of the form $\mathbf{v} = \sum_{i = 1}^n v_n \mathbf{a}_n$. The basis is defined by a specific head, call this `a`, and the indices are any arbitrary argument of `a`, so the pattern for a basis vector $\mathbf{a}_n$ is `a[__]`. Then I can make up a pattern for a coefficient times this,  $v_n \mathbf{a}_n$, as `_. a[__]`. I have two questions:

1) How can I make sure that the _. part doesn't have any `a` in it? I suspect this is with `FreeQ` but I'm a bit lost how to combine this with `_.`.

2) How can I now have a sum of any number of such terms > 1? To me this could be `Plus[(_. a[__])..]`, but when I run `MatchQ[ f a[1] + g a[2], Plus[(_. a[__])..]]` it evaluates to `False`

To give a couple of examples, let's call the pattern that I'm looking for `p`. (Note that my candidate `p` is `Plus[(_. a[__])..]`, and I don't understand why this doesn't work). Then I'd like the following expressions to evaluate to `True`;

```
MatchQ[f a[1] + g a[2], p]
MatchQ[f a[1] + g a[2] + a[15], p]
MatchQ[Sum[v[i] a[i], {i,100}], p]
MatchQ[a[1,2,3], p]
MatchQ[a[1], p]
MatchQ[f a[anythinginhere], p]
```

And some examples which don't match my pattern might be

```
MatchQ[f a, p]
MatchQ[a a[1], p]
MatchQ[Sum[v[i] a[i], {i,100}] + 5, p]
```

Comment: Would this work for you? `x = f a[1] + g a[2]; Cases[x, factor_ a[_] -> factor]`

Comment: Can you please include an example and the expected output? Thanks!

Comment: @Yarchik, I think what you're saying is something like what I want, but I need a pattern to define a function call by, so I want to return True/False with `MatchQ`, and not return a list of the coefficients. @AccidentalFourierTransform I have tried to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
ClearAll[fun]
fun[Optional[_?(FreeQ[a])] __a] := True
fun[x_Plus] := fun /@ And @@ x
fun[_] := False

fun[f a[1] + g a[2]]               (* True *)
fun[f a[1] + g a[2] + a[15]]       (* True *)
fun[Sum[v[i] a[i], {i, 100}]]      (* True *)
fun[a[1, 2, 3]]                    (* True *)
fun[a[1]]                          (* True *)
fun[f a[anythinginhere]]           (* True *)
fun[f a]                           (* False *)
fun[a a[1]]                        (* False *)
fun[Sum[v[i] a[i], {i, 100}] + 5]  (* False *)
```

as expected.

If you want to use `MatchQ`, then the pattern is `p = _?fun` (e.g., `MatchQ[a a[1], _?fun]`, which yields `False`).

OP asked for a more compact pattern that doesn't require an auxiliary function `fun`. A possibility is

```
p = (HoldPattern[+#] | #) &[(Optional[_?(FreeQ[a])] __a) ..];
```

so that, for example, `MatchQ[f a[1] + g a[2], p]` yields `True`, as required. We mention that this pattern is less clear and much less efficient than the solution above. I personally wouldn't use it, but to each their own.

Comment: OK thankyou, I like this and it does solve my problem. Is it possible to do it with a shorter syntax that doesn't involve defining a separate function? And do you know why my `Plus[(_. a[__])..]` doesn't work?

Comment: @Joe I don't think the code can get much shorter than this. There are several cases that have to be checked separately. Also, `.` is `Dot`, which is not the same thing as multiplication `Times`.

Comment: @Joe You have to replace `Dot` for `Times`, and you have to hold the pattern (for otherwise `Plus[X]` evaluates to `X` directly). I have updated the answer with the solution, but it is inefficient, so my recommendation is to use the first option, with `fun`.

Comment: Ahhh thank you, so `Plus` gets evaluated and `HoldPattern` was what I was missing. `.` is `Dot`, and `_.` is `Optional[Blank[]]`, http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsForSomeCommonTypesOfExpression.html gives a nice description of some usage cases. It removes the need for the different cases, but I can't work out how to combine it with `?FreeQ[a]`. Maybe I just didn't try very hard.

Comment: So `HoldPattern[Plus[_. a[__] ..]]` is nearly what I wanted, but it's just missing the `FreeQ` bit. I tried to put the condition on `_.` via `(x : _.) /; FreeQ[x, a]`, but this pulls up an error message about bad optional argument for some reason which I don't understand

Comment: @Joe Cool, I didn't know about `_.`. I think that `Optional[_?(FreeQ[a])] __a` does the trick.